# How can I copy the contents of a Panel to a richTextBox?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, richtextbox, panel

I have a Panel which the user of the application. The panel allows the user to enter their signature digitally. I would like to take the drawing from the panel and copy it to the very end of the richTextBox.

My current code for the panel is as follows:

```
public partial class Signature : Form
{
    SolidBrush color;
    float width;
    List<List<Point>> _lines;
    Boolean _mouseDown;

    public Signature()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _lines = new List<List<Point>>();
        color = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
        _mouseDown = false;
    }

    private void clear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _lines.Clear();
        sign.Invalidate();
    }

    private void panel1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        _mouseDown = true;
        _lines.Add(new List<Point>());
    }


    private void panel1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_mouseDown)
        {
            _lines.Last().Add(e.Location);
            sign.Invalidate();

        }
    }

    private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var lineSet in _lines)
        {
            if (lineSet.Count > 1)
            {
                e.Graphics.DrawLines(new Pen(Color.Black, 4.0F), lineSet.ToArray());
            }
        }
    }
    private void panel1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        _mouseDown = false;
    }

    private void use_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Signature successfully imported!", "Success!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
        Basic_Word_Processor.Instance.richTextBoxPrintCtrl1.SelectedText = "";
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

}

How can I take the drawing from the Panel and insert it to the end of the richTextBox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could first draw the signature to the `Bitmap` and then copy that bitmap through `Clipboard` into `RichTextBox`. You could try this but I must say that it is not tested:

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(panel1.Width, panel1.Height);
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, panel1.Width, panel1.Height);
panel1.DrawToBitmap(bmp, rect);
Clipboard.SetImage(bmp);
richTextBox1.Paste();
```

Or alternatively, you could draw `Lines` into the `Bitmap`

Comment: Can tweak to suite my needs. Thanks!